# What is a good Field-Effect Transistor Model?

Tags: fet, modeling

Hi guys I'm writing an electronics circuit simulator and I need a very simple and straightforward model for a field-effect transistor (as simple as the Ebers-Moll model for a BJT). I can use resistors, voltage sources, current sources, diodes, (I can also use a resistor with a very large resistance to measure the gate-source voltage).

What model would you suggest?

Comment: What has google turned up?

Comment: Use a voltage-controlled-current-source. And some capacitances from gate to source, and gate to drain.

Comment: Andy aka Literally the only model I found was the hybrid-PI model adapted for FET. It contains too many variables for my taste and even for BJT doesn't actually work.

Comment: analogsystemsrf Ok, what would be the relationship between the current and the voltage, then? How exactly would the components be placed?